# What is an alternative to Kotlin's `reduce` operation in Rust?

Tags: collections, functional-programming, rust, reduce

I encountered this competitive programming problem:

1. `nums` is a vector of integers (length `n`)
2. `ops` is a vector of strings containing `+` and `-` (length `n-1`)

It can be solved with the [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) operation in Kotlin like this:

```
val op_iter = ops.iterator();
nums.reduce {a, b ->
    when (op_iter.next()) {
        "+" -> a+b
        "-" -> a-b
        else -> throw Exception()
    }
}
```

`reduce` is described as:

> Accumulates value starting with the first element and applying operation from left to right to current accumulator value and each element.

It looks like Rust vectors do not have a `reduce` method. How would you achieve this task?

Comment: To be clear, while `Vec` lacks a `reduce` method, there is `fold` (equivalent to `reduce`) on `std::iter::Iterator` which you can get from a vector by doing `vec.iter()`

Answer (score 15):

Edited: since Rust version 1.51.0, this function is called [reduce](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce)
Be aware of similar function which is called [fold](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold). The difference is that `reduce` will produce `None` if iterator is empty while `fold` accepts accumulator and will produce accumulator's value if iterator is empty.

Outdated answer is left to capture the history of this function debating how to name it:

> There is no `reduce` in Rust 1.48. In many cases you can simulate it with `fold` but be aware that the semantics of the these functions are different. If the iterator is empty, `fold` will return the initial value whereas `reduce` returns `None`. If you want to perform multiplication operation on all elements, for example, getting result `1` for empty set is not too logical.

> Rust does have a [`fold_first`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold_first) function which is equivalent to Kotlin's `reduce`, but it is not stable yet. The [main discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/68125) is about naming it. It is a safe bet to use it if you are ok with nightly Rust because there is little chance the function will be removed. In the worst case, the name will be changed. If you need stable Rust, then use `fold` if you are Ok with an illogical result for empty sets. If not, then you'll have to implement it, or find a crate such as [reduce](https://docs.rs/reduce/0.1.3/reduce/).

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin's `reduce` takes the first item of the iterator for the starting point while Rust's [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) and [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) let you specify a custom starting point.

Here is an equivalent of the Kotlin code:

```
let mut it = nums.iter().cloned();
let start = it.next().unwrap();
it.zip(ops.iter()).try_fold(start, |a, (b, op)| match op {
    '+' => Ok(a + b),
    '-' => Ok(a - b),
    _ => Err(()),
})
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4ef1104ee3d59e2f8029533c0d2975ab)

Or since we're starting from a vector, which can be indexed:

```
nums[1..]
    .iter()
    .zip(ops.iter())
    .try_fold(nums[0], |a, (b, op)| match op {
        '+' => Ok(a + b),
        '-' => Ok(a - b),
        _ => Err(()),
    });
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=689b55cd9739aa899d448b70570171c2)

Comment: In many cases, you'll see this as `iterator.next().map(|first| iterator.fold(first, ...))`. That way, you avoid the panic from the `unwrap` and get an `Option` as the final result.